# Can a browser's "developer tools" help trace where/what click event handler was added?

Tags: jquery, events

I've assumed responsibility for maintaining a website where there's a pair of pseudo-buttons (`<a` tags dressed up like buttons) in the top right corner, for "log in" and "sign up". The client wants to change it for "log in" and "contact us" - the contact us being a different page to the sign up.

No problem, easy fix I thought - I swapped the `<a href="/signup"` to `<a href="/contactus"`. Pointing to the button on-page shows the correct URL in the status bar, but clicking on the button still goes to the signup page

I thus assumed that there's a click event handler at work doing the nav instead, and I'm trying to find out what that click event code is, or how it came to be attached

Chrome's inspect element doesn't tell me much (maybe it's because I can't understand it) - I switch to the "event listeners" tab after inspecting the button (or anything else in the DOM heirarchy above it), but I just get the same list of event handlers in there (for any DOM element in the hierarchy) and I don't see anything that helps me determine the source code that is run. Chrome says they're linked to `all.js` - that file is 430kb of minified script, I'm not sure which web library it's from, so "line 13 in all.js" isn't much help. Does anything in the tree under `li.sign-up.wide` help me get back to the click event handling code?

[image]

Edge/IE didn't have much info either.. In these browsers, the event listeners tab is predominantly empty for elements back towards the DOM root, apart from the `li` holding the `a` element, which does have a click event listed, but again this just links back to somewhere in all.js - IE does at least tell me it's on line 2 at column 1752, but I have a hard time believing this is the code I want, because as noted `all.js` is just a mass of minified script.

[image]

I searched all of the source code (using a standard Find in Files type search) for anything relevant I can think of: `bind` (the jquery function to bind an event), `click` (the event bound - seems sometimes jquery.click() is used), `signup` (the url the user is sent to by the click handler) and I turned up a few things that looked promising:

```
    var bindMiniSignup = function () {

        $('#sign-up-widget .sign-up.wide, #sign-up-widget .sign-up.mobile').bind('click',function(){
            Main.ExpandSignUpForm();
            return false;
        });

        $('#sign-up-widget .log-in.wide, #sign-up-widget .log-in.mobile').bind('click',function(){
            Main.ExpandLogInForm();
            return false;
        });
    }
```

These class and ID names surely refer to the element I'm trying to change:

[image]

and this function `bindMiniSignup` is called a few times in various places (document.ready for example) so I was certain it was what I was looking for. Alas, commenting out  the body of the function so the bindings weren't made had no effect on the site; it still behaved as before (cleared cache to make sure the new JS had been loaded)

So my question is; if you were handed the task of finding and changing the PHP or JS file where an element has a `click` binding, how would you go about finding the code that is called when the element is clicked (or the code that performs the binding)? Is there a way to make the browser break immediately after I click this button, so I can find the actual click handler code running, and hence I can search all the source code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track, but jQuery has used [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for a very long time to do event binding.

Additionally, based on the fact that the file that's binding the event is called `all.js`, you probably need to perform an intermediate compilation or minification step to the source code. This may be the reason your changes aren't having any effect.

Check the project root for any Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, etc. files since they'll indicate what tools were used to do the compilation/pre-processing.

Comment: There's a bunch of less files along with the css, so it seems conceivable that the "compile web resources into other formats" thing applies to JS too, thanks for the pointer, I'll have a rummage..

Comment: Ahh... The bunch of `<script` tags I found in the header.htm are wrapped in something Iv'e never seen before: `<check if="{{DEBUG}}"><true> ..lots of script tags here pointing to each js file</true><false> single script tag to all.js </false></check>` - so now to find the tool that prepares all.js ..